# How to get only visible text from a EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText for a code editor running on Android. I'm applying syntax highlighting to the content, it's working well except for large Strings where the EditText scrolls off screen - the syntax highlighting is being applied to the entire Spannable on every key press.

Does anyone know how I'd go about capturing only the text that is visible to the user?

I can only think of nasty hack based on cursor position but that would break when the user scrolls.

Comment: how do you apply the syntax highlighting ?

Comment: @pskink - It's not really relevant I don't think, but I'm using:  spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0); 

The problem isn't the syntax highlighting, it's that it's being applied to the entire content of the EditText - even content that's offscreen, so when editing a sourcefile with 100+ lines of code things become very sluggish.

Comment: great, so first apply it to rhe whole buffer and then using TextWatcher apply it to the new text only

Comment: That's an awesome idea, simple too!

Comment: but coming back to the original question, see TextView.getLayout()

Answer (score 4):

Can use the function below to get the visible text offsets.  You'd input the raw x,y corners of the edit text, and it will return the nearest text offset (i.e. character position).

```
    EditText et = ;
    et.getOffsetForPosition(x, y);
```

Once you know start / end of the visible text, you set your span accordingly.  If you are just changing coloring (i.e. not height / width) then there shouldn't be any circular dependency.

Comment: Just to clarify, does this mean something like `int firstVisibleChar = et.getOffsetForPosition(et.getX(),et.getY())` and `int lastVisibleChar = et.getOffsetForPosition(et.getLength(), et.getHeight())` would be used to capture all visible text?

Comment: @PPartisan It seems to be true. I've just tried it with a text that doesn't fit into visible area. However it should be `et.getWidth()` as `et.getLength()` doesn't exist.